# How do I hook up a HandlerExceptionResolver

Tags: spring, exception

How do I hook up a HandlerExceptionResolver to catch exceptions and errors?

**web.xml**

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/support/500.jsp</location>
  </error-page>

  <error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
    <location>/support/500.jsp</location>
  </error-page>

   <error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
    <location>/support/500.jsp</location>
  </error-page>
```

**500.jsp**

```
//How do I get a stack trace or specific error message in here?
```

Answer (score 1):

a simple example for both unchecked and checked exception would be

```
 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver">
<property name="exceptionMappings">
  <map>
    <entry key="DataAccessException" value="data-error" />
    <entry key="com.stuff.MyAppRuntimeException" value="app-unchecked-error" />
    <entry key="com.stuff.MyAppCheckedException" value="app-checked-error" />
  </map>
</property>
<property name="defaultErrorView" value="general-error"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Sweet! Thanks for the response Syed Saulat. But how do I regurgitate these caught errors/exceptions onto the jsp page? Do I have to use a method from my controller/set parameters or is there some handy spring way of doing this?

Comment: and the part where you put "<entry key="com.stuff.MyAppRuntimeException"" Is that where you would indicate a class a that would potentially cause the exception exception?

Comment: `<c:forEach items="${exception.stackTrace}" var="element">
    <c:out value="${element}">
</c:forEach>`

You'd need to add some formatting, of course.

Comment: com.stuff.MyAppRuntimeException is the Exception class you have to build your self extending from RuntimeException